# Selecting multiple rows from the same column - joins

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, join

I have three tables: `Ses user`, `Ses Moves` and `Moves`.

- `Ses user` has the columns `id`, `user`, and `ses-id`.
- `Ses Moves` has the columns `ses-id` and `move-id`.
- `Moves` has the columns `id` and `name`.

I joined `Ses user` with `Ses Moves` by `id` and `ses-id`. I also joined `Ses Moves` with `Moves` by `move-id` and `id`.

The only problem is there are multiple rows in the `Moves` table that have the same id so it looks something like this:

```
+------+-=---+
|Ses ID| Name|
+------+-----+
|  10  | Bite|
+------+-----+
|  10  | Eat |
+------+-----+
|  10  |Crush|
+------+-----+
|  10  |Punch|
+------+-----+
|  10  |Stare|
+------+-----+
|  10  | Rest|
+------+-----+
```

I want the SQL statement to return something like this:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|Ses ID|Name Move 1|Name Move 2|Name Move 3|Name Move 4|Name Move 5|Name Move 6|
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  10  |   Bite    |   Eat     |   Crush   |   Punch   |  Stare    |   Rest    |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

What can do to have it return this?

If it helps to know, I'm using PHP to run the query.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to achieve this?

Comment: Most likely, with the setup you have now, I doubt a single query will produce the exact format you're wanting; however, since you're using PHP, you can process the data after it has been queried.  You'll simply loop through the responses and tabulate the data using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't all too difficult a feat with dynamic SQL (assuming you don't know the maximum number of names a given Ses ID could have. Here's an example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- CREATE TABLE #table ([Ses ID] INT, Name NVARCHAR(255));
-- INSERT #table VALUES (10, 'Bite'),(10,'Eat'),(10,'Crush'),(10,'Punch'),(9,'Hugs'),(9,'Kisses');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = '
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [Ses ID], Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Ses ID] ORDER BY Name) RN
    FROM #table)
SELECT [Ses ID]'
, @MaxRN INT = (SELECT MAX(RN)
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Ses ID] ORDER BY Name) RN
    FROM #table) T)
, @i INT = 1;

WHILE @i <= @MaxRN BEGIN
    SET @SQL += ', (SELECT Name FROM CTE WHERE RN = ' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(255)) + ' AND [Ses ID] = C.[Ses ID]) [Name Move ' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(255)) + ']';
    SET @i += 1;
END

SET @SQL += '
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY [Ses ID]
ORDER BY [Ses ID]';

EXEC(@SQL);

-- DROP TABLE #table;
```